# Issue with validation message of associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models Student and Image. A student may have multiple images, maximum 4 images.

In my Student model I have added

```
has_many :images, dependent: :destroy
```

Image model

```
mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader

belongs_to :student, foreign_key: 'student_id'

validate do |record|
  record.validate_image_number
end


def validate_image_number
  return unless self.student
  if self.student.images(:reload).count >= 4
    errors.add(:base, 'Image limit exceeded')
  end
end
```

StudentController.rb

```
Student.transaction do
  @student.save!

  if params[:images].present?
    params[:images]['image'].each do |a|
      @image = @student.images.create!(image: a)
    end
  end
end
return render json: { 'status': 'success'}
rescue => e
  puts e
  if @student
    return render json: {'errors': @student.errors}, statuts: 422
  else
    return render json: { 'status': 'failure'}
  end
```

I am now getting student.errors as {}, if I upload more than 4 images, but the exception message is 'Image limit exceeded'. How can I add the error message of Image model in Student error list

Comment: What’s the issue you’re seeing?

Comment: I think the image model error will get in @image.errors. I want it in Student model errors

Comment: Try using a nested form to add images to the student. That way any errors associated with the form should come up on the student. Let me know if you are familiar with that or would like a further example.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to do an API

Comment: Got ya. I think you can apply the concept still. I am now missing a bit more context of your code  (e.g., are you also responsible for the client side?) but essentially the params payload coming back should have `images_attributes` with the images params nested under the key `student`. You would still add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :images` on the student model.